# Why Unicode Charater θ not supported in PGSQL

Tags: c++, postgresql, character-encoding

I was working with Postgresql with C++ and tried to insert unicode character αβγδεζηθ.

Fired insert query in some database table and found that 'θ' is not supported character.

For this i run gdb. for this character i.e. 'θ' it is showing gibrish character.

1. Can i find the character set supported by Postgresql.
2. Does Pgsql support this character.
3. Is there any way to support this character.

**Note :** 1. I am using c++ to fire this command. and it does not save this
    value.
           2. Database is UTF8 compliant because when i remove this 'θ' insert query is fired successfully.

Comment: It isn't clear what gdb has to do with this. "For this I run gdb". Huh? For what?

Comment: @Craig Ringer actually i am debugging the code, i fired query from C++ into the database and used gdb to print the output at each and every line i.e. added breakpoint and when printing the output results to gibrish characters.

Comment: Then you've added another variable into your mix: The character encoding of the terminal you're running gdb in. What's the output of the `locale` command in that terminal? And  what about the rest - `\l` or `SHOW server_encoding;` and `SHOW client_encoding;`? Please add these as *edits to the original question* then comment here when done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, PostgreSQL supports `θ`, the character *`U+03b8` Greek Small Letter Theta*, both in unicode escape and literal form:

```
regress=> SELECT 'θ', E'\u03b8';
 ?column? | ?column? 
----------+----------                                                                                                                                                          
 θ        | θ                                                                                                                                                                  
(1 row)
```

At a guess, your database encoding or client encoding don't support it, or perhaps more likely given your mention of "gibberish", your `client_encoding` doesn't match the encoding of the data you're actually sending.

Check the database encoding with `\l` in psql, or `SHOW server_encoding;`. Get the client encoding with `SHOW client_encoding;` *from the client connection with the problem*.

I'd say you're probably sending UTF-8 or UTF-16 data to the server but telling the server it is iso-8859-1 or windows-1252 or vice versa. Though `θ` isn't in those encodings; you must be using something else, or sending data that's already mangled by another invalid transformation before even getting to PostgreSQL.

It would be helpful if you showed:

- The exact "gibberish" produced and the matching input
- The *raw bytes* of the C string that you send to PostgreSQL, as hex escapes

Comment: I have checked the database encoding is UTF-8. Also wants to update that you are right that 'θ' is supported because its the random behavior. Also the Client side encoding is also ok. Because it is supporting UTF8 characters rather than 'θ' but sometimes. 
I am finding out, might be some issue in the code.

Comment: I'm confident it's a character set handling problem in your code, or something more subtle like memory issues.

Comment: If it is character encoding problem then no characters should be supported because for the string **'αβγδεζηθ'**  supported only **'θ'** is not supported that is if i enter **'αβγδεζη'** then the values are submitted successfully (see i have omitted theta)

Comment: @vermaraj Actually, that's not necessarily the case at all. Please show your `client_encoding` and the output of the `locale` command on your computer. Also, what's your PostgreSQL version (`select version()`).